# Easiest way to subset within a multidimensional range?

Tags: r

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before, or if I have missed something obvious.

I have two data sets, 'olddata' and 'newdata'

```
set.seed(0)
olddata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0,5), y = runif(10, 0, 5), z = runif(10,-10,10))
newdata <- data.frame(x = -5:5, z = -5:5)
```

I create a model from the old data, and want to predict values from the new data

```
mymodel <- lm(y ~ x+z, data = olddata)
predict.lm(mymodel, newdata)
```

However, I'd like to restrict the range of variables in 'newdata' to the range of variables on which the model was trained.

of course I could do this:

```
 newnewdata <- subset(newdata, 
                      x < max(olddata$x) & x > min(olddata$x) &
                      z < max(olddata$z) & z > max(olddata$z))
```

But this gets intractable over many dimensions. Is there a less repetitive way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that all the values in your `newdata` are already within the appropriate ranges, so there's nothing there to subset. If we expand the ranges of `newdata`:

```
set.seed(0)
olddata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0,5), y = runif(10, 0, 5), z = runif(10,-10,10))
newdata <- data.frame(x = -10:10, z = -10:10)

newdata
     x   z
1  -10 -10
2   -9  -9
3   -8  -8
4   -7  -7
5   -6  -6
6   -5  -5
7   -4  -4
8   -3  -3
9   -2  -2
10  -1  -1
11   0   0
12   1   1
13   2   2
14   3   3
15   4   4
16   5   5
17   6   6
18   7   7
19   8   8
20   9   9
21  10  10
```

Then all we need to do is identify the ranges for each variable of `olddata` and then loop through as many iterations of `subset` as `newdata` has columns:

```
ranges <- sapply(olddata, range, na.rm = TRUE)

for(i in 1:ncol(newdata)) {
  col_name <- colnames(newdata)[i]

  newdata <- subset(newdata, 
    newdata[,col_name] >= ranges[1, col_name] &
      newdata[,col_name] <= ranges[2, col_name])
}

newdata
    x  z
4  -7 -7
5  -6 -6
6  -5 -5
7  -4 -4
8  -3 -3
9  -2 -2
10 -1 -1
11  0  0
12  1  1
13  2  2
14  3  3
15  4  4
16  5  5
17  6  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using the *apply family (using SchaunW's newdata):

```
set.seed(0)
olddata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 5), y = runif(10, 0, 5), z = runif(10,-10,10))
newdata <- data.frame(x = -10:10, z = -10:10)

minmax <- sapply(olddata[-2], range)
newdata[apply(newdata, 1, function(a) all(a > minmax[1,] & a < minmax[2,])), ]
```

Some care is required because I have assumed the columns of `olddata` (after dropping the second column) are identical to `newdata`.

Brevity comes at the cost of speed. After increasing `nrow(newdata)` to 2000 to emphasis the difference I found:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  orizon()          100   2.193   27.759     2.191    0.002          0         0
2 SchaunW()          100   0.079    1.000     0.075    0.004          0         0
```

My guess at the main cause is that repeated subsetting avoids testing whether rows meet the criteria examined after they are excluded.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a vectorized approach. `apply` is a for loop, but your implementation is looping over every single row of the data instead of just over each column. I would guess that's where the speed differences are coming from.

Comment: Noted. I have edited my answer. I also explored whether iterating over rows was the reason for the perfomance difference. Using mapply over columns was only 2.6 times as slow as iterated subsetting.